# Maya scripting: Issue when creating user interfaces (rows and columns)

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, row, maya

I would like to create a user UI which has an item distribution like this:

[image]

On the large rectangle I would like a slide bar. The problem is that I cannot get it to work. I try to specify two different layouts in the same window and Maya goes funny telling me that there are too many children or something like this. Here I put what I have so far:

```
cmds.window(windowID, title='Towers Of Hanoi', sizeable=False, resizeToFitChildren=True)
cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2, columnWidth=[(1,90),(2,80)], columnOffset=[(1,'right',5),(2,'right',5)])

cmds.text(label='Num. of Disks:')
cmds.separator( h=10, style='none' )

cmds.separator( h=5, style='none' )
cmds.separator( h=5, style='none' )

# WHAT DO I DO HERE?
diskNumUIField = cmds.intScrollBar(min=2, max=12, value=0, step=1, largeStep=2)
cmds.separator( h=10, style='none' ) 
# This thing above is where my problem is?

cmds.separator( h=5, style='none' )
cmds.separator( h=5, style='none' )

cmds.button(label='Place Disks', width=75, command=blablabla())
cmds.button(label='Clear All', width=75, command=blablabla())

cmds.separator( h=5, style='none' )
cmds.separator( h=5, style='none' )

cmds.button(label='Solve it!', width=75, command=blablabla())
cmds.button(label='Exit', width=75, command=blablabla())

cmds.separator( h=5, style='none' )
cmds.separator( h=5, style='none' )

cmds.showWindow()
```

[image: I don't want that to happen]

Thanks for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `columnLayout` with nested `rowLayout`s:

[image]

```
cmds.window(windowID, title='Towers Of Hanoi', sizeable=False, resizeToFitChildren=True)
cmds.columnLayout(columnAttach=('both', 5), columnWidth=200)

cmds.text(label='Num. of Disks:')

diskNumUIField = cmds.intScrollBar(min=2, max=12, value=2, step=1, largeStep=2)

cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2, columnWidth2=(90, 80))

cmds.button(label='Place Disks', width=75, command=blablabla)
cmds.button(label='Clear All', width=75, command=blablabla)

cmds.setParent('..')

cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2, columnWidth2=(90, 80))

cmds.button(label='Solve it!', width=75, command=blablabla)
cmds.button(label='Exit', width=75, command=blablabla)
cmds.showWindow()
```

---

**NB:** your button commands had parentheses. This calls the function *before* building the button. You need to remove parentheses in order for the function to be called on click.

Comment: You were right mhlester with the parentheses (I didn't notice). Thank you very much for the right piece of code, now I see how to structure better the UIs, you solved my issue, thanks.

Comment: Honestly, and I know it's more work, but if you want to use Maya UI, formLayout is the most flexible. That or Qt. Nice thing about Qt is it's portable. I can use the same UI in Maya as Nuke

Comment: Never thought of Qt forms to be applied to Maya. I will do a little bit of research. Do you design it using PyQt or something?

Comment: It's actually PySide, but yeah, worth exploring

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is a [intSlider](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2012/en_us/CommandsPython/intSlider.html) or a [intSliderGrp](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2012/en_us/CommandsPython/intSliderGrp.html), not a intScrollBar, that does not exist...thanks @theodox :P

Comment: There's no such thing as 'intScrollBar'.  If you want a scrollable list you would use [scollLayout](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/scrollLayout.html) with another layout (like a column) inside it